# AJAX to open Modal in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I'm creating a "single page" app where I want to load different views in my dashboard
with AJAX. I'm using jQuery for the AJAX calls. I've created contollers foreach of my views
(is this considered to be a bad practice? Will it be better to just make one controller with multiple methods for loading all of my views?) 
and everything is working just fine except the actual modal I need to show with AJAX.

I can preview the response (modal) with my developer tool, but I'm not getting it to show right in my eyes.

At start, this specific modal was included in one of my views where I appended every one of my other views with AJAX,
but I founded it as bad practice and created a new view for that modal.

**So here's my controller to load the view (modal):**

```
<?php

    class Add_user extends CI_Controller
    {

        public function __construct()
        {

            parent::__construct();
            $this->load->model('user_model');
            $this->load->model('subject_model');
        }

        public function index()
        {

        $data['subjects'] = $this->subject_model->get_all_subjects();
        $data['schools'] = $this->subject_model->get_all_schools();

        $this->load->view('new_user', $data);
        }
    }

?>
```

**Here's the view for the modal (pretty much standard HTML with some CodeIgniter's helper methods):**

```
<?php $this->load->helper('form'); ?>
<?php $attributes = array(
        'id' => 'add_user_form'
    );
?>

<?php echo form_open('users/add_user', $attributes); ?>

    <span class="close_form_button_add_user_form">&times;</span>

    <div class="form_header">
        <h1>Create New User</h1>
    </div> <!-- end of form_header -->

    <!-- Message and response elements-->
    <div class="loading_spinner" id="loading_spinner_add_user" style="display:none;"></div>
    <div class="login_error" id="new_user_error" style="display:none">
        <span class="close_error">&times;</span>
    </div>
    <div class="front_success" id="new_user_success" style="display:none"></div>


    <div class="form_row">
        <div class="sign-pass">
            <label for="f_name">Etunimi</label>
            <input type="text" name="f_name"/>
        </div>

        <div class="sign-pass-again">
            <label for="l_name">Sukunimi</label>
            <input type="text" name="l_name"/>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form_row">
        <div class="sign-pass">
            <label for="email">Sähköpostiosoite</label>
            <input type="email" name="email"/>
        </div>

        <div class="sign-pass-again">
            <label for="email_confirm">Sähköposti uudelleen</label>
            <input type="email" name="email_confirm"/>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form_row">
        <label for="phone_number">Puhelinnumero (valinnainen)</label>
        <input type="text" name="phone_number" class="full-width" />
    </div>

    <div class="form_row">
        <div class="sign-pass">
            <label for="user_type">Valitse käyttäjätyyppi</label>
            <select name="user_type" class="add_user_select" id="select_user_type">
                <option value="">Käyttäjätyyppi</option>

                <option value="admin">Hallinto</option>
                <option value="moderator">Hallinto 2</option>
                <option value="enduser">Pääkäyttäjä</option>
            </select>
        </div>

        <div class="sign-pass-again">
            <input type="submit" name="submit_user" value="Luo käyttäjä" class="login_submit" id="submit_user" style="margin: 5px 24px 0px 0px;"/> </br>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form_row" id="add_user_optional_information">
        <label for="school">Choose school</label>
            <select name="school" class="add_user_select_optional">
                <option value="">School</option>
                <?php  foreach($schools as $school) :?>
                <option value="<?=$school['id']?>"><?=$school['name']?></option>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </select>


        <label for="subject">Choose subject</label>
            <select name="subject" class="add_user_select_optional" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">
                <option value="">Subject</option>
                <?php  foreach($subjects as $subject) :?>
                <option value="<?=$subject['id']?>"><?=$subject['name']?></option>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </select>
    </div>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

**And here's a part of my JS file for the AJAX response:**

```
$(".add_user").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = $(this).attr("href");

        $.ajax({

            url: url,
            async: false,
            data: url,
            success: function(data) {

            // Here's the part what I'm thinking is wrong

            $("form#add_user_form").easyModal({
                top: 80,
                autoOpen: true,
                overlayOpacity: 0.1,
                overlayColor: "#000000",
                overlayClose: true,
                closeButtonClass: "span.close_form_button_add_user_form"
            });
        }           
        });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: I'm not clear on what problem you're having. You've written _"but I'm not getting it to show right in my eyes"_ but I don't understand what that means. Can you clarify your problem?

Comment: Sorry about my bad writing, been coding for hours and I'm pretty tired. The problem is that the modal isn't opening. I can preview it within my "Network" tab on Developer tools.

Answer (score 0):

if do you want to call modal first in view must have trigger 
example :

```
<button class="btn btn-default" onclick="open_modal()"><i> class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></i> Refresh</button>
```

where onclick="open_modal() to call javascript function like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function open_modal()
    {
     save_method = 'add';
     $('#form')[0].reset(); // reset form on modals
     $('.form-group').removeClass('has-error'); // clear error class
     $('.help-block').empty(); // clear error string
     $('#modal_form').modal('show'); // show bootstrap modal
     $('.modal-title').text('Create New User'); // Set Title to Bootstrap modal title     }
</script>
```

finally this what format inside your modals

```
<!-- Bootstrap modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="modal_form" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h3 class="modal-title"><center></center></h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body form">
                <form action="#" id="form" class="form-horizontal">
                    <div class="form_row">
        <div class="sign-pass">
            <label for="f_name">Etunimi</label>
            <input type="text" name="f_name"/>
        </div>

        <div class="sign-pass-again">
            <label for="l_name">Sukunimi</label>
            <input type="text" name="l_name"/>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form_row">
        <div class="sign-pass">
            <label for="email">Sähköpostiosoite</label>
            <input type="email" name="email"/>
        </div>

        <div class="sign-pass-again">
            <label for="email_confirm">Sähköposti uudelleen</label>
            <input type="email" name="email_confirm"/>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form_row">
        <label for="phone_number">Puhelinnumero (valinnainen)</label>
        <input type="text" name="phone_number" class="full-width" />
    </div>

    <div class="form_row">
        <div class="sign-pass">
            <label for="user_type">Valitse käyttäjätyyppi</label>
            <select name="user_type" class="add_user_select" id="select_user_type">
                <option value="">Käyttäjätyyppi</option>

                <option value="admin">Hallinto</option>
                <option value="moderator">Hallinto 2</option>
                <option value="enduser">Pääkäyttäjä</option>
            </select>
        </div>

        <div class="sign-pass-again">
            <input type="submit" name="submit_user" value="Luo käyttäjä" class="login_submit" id="submit_user" style="margin: 5px 24px 0px 0px;"/> </br>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form_row" id="add_user_optional_information">
        <label for="school">Choose school</label>
            <select name="school" class="add_user_select_optional">
                <option value="">School</option>
                <?php  foreach($schools as $school) :?>
                <option value="<?=$school['id']?>"><?=$school['name']?></option>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </select>


        <label for="subject">Choose subject</label>
            <select name="subject" class="add_user_select_optional" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">
                <option value="">Subject</option>
                <?php  foreach($subjects as $subject) :?>
                <option value="<?=$subject['id']?>"><?=$subject['name']?></option>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </select>
    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" id="btnSave" onclick="save()" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
            </div>
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
<!-- End Bootstrap modal -->
```

try this code if u have error try to capture

Answer (score 0):

There is a pretty easy solution i found. Try this

In Html:

```
<a class="btn" data-target="#myModal" data-toggle="modal">Open modal</a>
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div id="render_modal"></div>
</div>
```

In Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

      $.ajax({
         url: '<?php echo base_url('Modal')?>',
         type: 'post',
         success:function(){
            $('#render_modal').html(data);
            $('a[data-target="cart_modal"]').click(function(){
                $('#myModal').modal('show');
            });
         }
      });

});
```

In Modal Controller:

```
echo "
        <div class=\"modal-dialog\"> 
            <div class=\"modal-content\">
                <div class=\"modal-header\">
                <button type=\"button\" class=\"close\" data-dismiss=\"modal\" aria-hidden=\"true\"> &times; </button>
This is Modal body
                </div>
                <div class=\"modal-body\"> 
                This is Modal body
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    ";
```

Thanks.